# Will Team Foundation Version Control ignore the git folder?

Tags: git, team-foundation-server, version-control

I have a Visual Studio project that I am going to add to our companies TFVC.  I will be doing so from inside Visual Studio.  I use git from the command line while I'm developing.  When I add my Visual Studio project to TFVC will my git folder be ignored and not added to TFVC?  I don't want to clutter up TFS with my micro iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on TFS 2017 (and maybe 2015) you can have both TFVC and Git repositories in the same project.
The other way would be to use a `.tfignore` file to ignore the `.git` folder https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dstfs/2016/01/29/tfignore-usage-in-team-foundation-server/